# Can we change the location of springBeanConfiguration file in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-inf, deployment-descriptor

I have developed a Spring MVC web application. In this application I have two containers and the location of the spring bean configuration file is:

```
/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
```

I have changed the name of the spring bean cfg file but I also want to change the location to:

```
/com/nt/cfg/applicationContext.xml
```

However, Spring is not recognizing any location other than `/WEB-INF/`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare de route when you create the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

The default location is the resources folder.

Hope this help you.

Comment: no zaloan i am not worry about to create container explicitly i wan to change the location deployment-descriptor of spring mvc DispatcherServlet  supply WebApplicationContext container that is by default search spring bean configuration  file in /WEB-INF/ directory

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES, you can change the name and location of the configuration file but you have to make spring aware of the new name and location.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
```

It will load the context from `context.xml` file (context.xml should be present in classpath).
You can create new Applicationcontext by passing desired XML file as parameter to constructor.

So after changing name and location of the file you have to register here for spring reference so that spring can find the configuration file.

Comment: no i am not interested to create explicitly create container by  user in spring dispatcher servlet already provide   predefined ioc container WebApplicationContext with fixed location /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml but i want to change the location of spring bean cfg file in eclipse where our java classes are reside